# Can I use a variable as a text property when calling class window?

Tags: regex, vbscript, properties, qtp, hp-uft

I have a child object class `window` with a parameter `regexptitle`, so text being changed dynamically depending on the regular expression. I need to check if this window is opened and active using variable. I tried to put there string but it didn't help. Please help me find a solution.

Example of code repeated:

```vb
If Window("Excel").Window("Prompts for Project Analysis"). Exist Then ...
```

```vb
If Window("Excel").Window("Prompts for Engagements"). Exist Then ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I read your question correctly, you should be able to achieve the goal using descriptive programming with this:

```
If Window("Excel").Window("regexptitle:=Prompts for.*"). Exist Then
```

Or if you have at least one version of the window learned in the object repository, add the `regexptitle` property to the test object details under Description properties, set it to a regular expression and set its value to be "Prompts for.*" - this will cause UFT to recognise all windows of this class with a `regexptitle` beginning "Prompts for" as this object (assuming the other recognition properties match up as well, and you get to use the OR-friendly object name in your code.

Let me know if that works for you, or if you need further help.